# Where should I instantiate entities from database in a Three-tier app?

Tags: database, oop, 3-tier

I'm creating a **3-tiers** application, and I encountered a problem.
I have a database that holds data about customers and a class that represents a customer entity in my app. The problem is, I don't know if I should instantiate a customer entity in the **Data tier** or in the **Application tier**.

Creating the customer entity in the **Application tier** seems more correct, because the **Data tier** is supposed to only query the data, but this would mean that I need to use "raw/unformatted" data in the **Application tier** and that don't look good either.

Anyone know the "correct" way to deal with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database persists state and before it can be queried that sate must be saved. A new Customer entity is instantiated by the Application then sent to Persistance to be saved. When the application needs a certain Customer from the db, the Persistence (usually the Repository) restores the Customer.

Note that the Customer is a Business entity, related but not the same with a Customer table or a Customer ORM entity which is simply a data structure modeled from the database point of view to be optimized for queries.

Comment: So you're saying that I should instantiate a customer in the Application tier when it's going to be saved, and in the Data tier when it's being restored from the db ?

Comment: I'm saying that a NEW Customer is instantiated where you need it and 99.99% of times you will need it in the App layer, the Data layer just saves/restores entities.

Comment: Yeah but when the Data layer restore the entity it instantiate it, no ? I mean in my db connection class, I'll have to write something like this `Customer c = new Customer(data);`. Or should I put that code in the App layer, and use the data I got from the Data layer, making some like this `Data d = dbConnector.getCustomerData(); Customer c = new Customer(d);` ?

Comment: No, the Data layer instantiates the customer in this case.